# How to get a calendar view from multiple calendars efficiently with MS Graph API

Tags: .net, rest, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), we can retrieve a calendar view from user's default calendar, from a default calendar group, or from a specific calendar group.

I am wondering if I'd be able to get a calendar view from **multiple Outlook calendars** given a specific start date and end date.

The straightforward approach could be:

1. Call "[list calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" endpoint

   `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars`
2. For each calendar ID from previous results, call "[list calendar view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" endpoint

   `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}`

The problem with this approach is that it's not quite efficient. Imagine if I have 20+ calendars and for each for them I will need to call the calendar view endpoint 20 times. No good...

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch request for the second point.

Example:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var start = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");
var end = today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", start),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", end)
};

var requestIds = new List<string>();
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
foreach (var calendarId in calIds)
{
    var calendarViewRequest = client.Users["id"].Calendars[calendarId].CalendarView.Request(queryOptions);
    var requestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(calendarViewRequest);
    requestIds.Add(requestId);
}
var returnedResponse = await client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
foreach (var requestId in requestIds)
{
    var result = await returnedResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<UserCalendarViewCollectionResponse>(requestId);
}
```

JSON batch requests are currently limited to 20 individual requests.

Resource:

[Batch reqeust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp)

[Batching limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching)